# Delphi: Convert from windows-1251 to Shift-JIS

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a string `'ＭＩＲＯＫＵ'`. I want to convert this string to `'%82l%82h%82q%82n%82j%82t'`. Below is my current function which I have used for converting:

```
function MyEncode(const S: string; const CodePage: Integer): string;
var
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  b: Byte;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
begin
  Encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(CodePage);
  try
    Bytes := Encoding.GetBytes(S);
  finally
    Encoding.Free;
  end;

  sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
  try
    for b in Bytes do begin
      sb.Append('%');
      sb.Append(IntToHex(b, 2));
    end;
    Result := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`MyEncode('ＭＩＲＯＫＵ', 932)` returns `'%82%6C%82%68%82%71%82%6E%82%6A%82%74'`. I don't expect this result. I expect `'%82l%82h%82q%82n%82j%82t'`. Are there any functions to convert it correctly?

Comment: I want to convert this string '**ＭＩＲＯＫＵ**' to  '**%82l%82h%82q%82n%82j%82t**'.

Comment: And what does your function produce? Please improve (edit) your question. You did not say what are you passing in for the `CodePage` parameter and you did not say what are you getting back from the function and why is that wrong.

Comment: What is the question. You didn't ask a question. At all. You said, "I want to do X. This is my function to do X." Please ask a question.

Comment: There is still no question asked. But I wonder why you would expect that a 2 digit hex string could be 3 digits long. Try and read your own code and think about what you wrote.

Comment: I have string '**ＭＩＲＯＫＵ**', I want to convert it to this string '**%82l%82h%82q%82n%82j%82t**'. i have use __MyEncode('ＭＩＲＯＫＵ', 932)__ but i didn't get string i need '**%82l%82h%82q%82n%82j%82t**'. I just got this string '__%82%6C%82%68%82%71%82%6E%82%6A%82%74__'.  So are there any function to convert it?

Comment: That's not a question. That is a statement. Do you actually have a question. Please ask it by way of an edit and then we can remove all these comments. Again, ask yourself why you would expect to get three characters from `IntToHex(b, 2)`. Why? Try to learn to think yourself a little harder. Don't give up so readily.

Comment: "ＭＩＲＯＫＵ" consists entirely of Unicode characters.  These are neither representable in Win1251 nor Shift-JIS...

Comment: Now we have a question. That's good. But can you now explain why you are expecting `IntToHex(b, 2)` to give the results you expect. How could it ever return `82q` for instance? That has three characters rather than 2, and the final one is not a hexadecimal digit. You need to stop asking us to solve your problem, and step back and work out what your problem really is. You are getting ahead of yourself. Until you have a clear understanding of the problem domain it is pointless to attempt to solve anything. Please will you take 10 minutes to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct, just not what you are expecting. `%6C`, for example, is the ascii representation for `l`. So you could try something like this instead:

```
function MyEncode(const S: string; const CodePage: Integer): string;
var
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  b: Byte;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
begin
  Encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(CodePage);
  try
    Bytes := Encoding.GetBytes(S);
  finally
    Encoding.Free;
  end;

  sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
  try
    for b in Bytes do begin
      if (b in [65..90]) or (b in [97..122]) then
      begin
        sb.Append( char(b)); // normal ascii
      end  
      else
      begin
        sb.Append('%');
        sb.Append(IntToHex(b, 2));
      end;
    end;
    Result := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or you could leave it as is!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks you for your time to read my question.

Comment: In URL encoding, *ANY* octet can be hex encoded, regardless of its value. The receiver is required to decode all of them equally. So the original code was perfectly fine. However, if you are going to filter out "safe" octets from encoding, consider including `48..57` (`'0'..'9'`) in the range. And there are a few other ASCII characters that are also "safe" and do not require encoding (`'-'`, `'.'`, `'_'`, and `'~'`). See [RFC 3986 section 2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2) for more details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau which is why I said 'Or you could leave it as is'